# aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations does not work. Assign static IP to LoadBalancer service using k8s on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-elb

I use aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations assign static IP to LoadBalancer service using k8s on AWS. The version of EKS is v1.16.13. The doc at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.16.0/staging/src/k8s.io/legacy-cloud-providers/aws/aws.go#L208-L211, line 210 and 211 says "static IP addresses for the NLB. Only supported on elbv2 (NLB)". I do not know what the elbv2 is. I use the code below. But, I did not get static IP. Is elbv2 the problem? How do I use elbv2? Please also refer to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/69263 as well.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations: "eipalloc-0187de53333555567"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
```

Answer (score 2):

have in mind that you need 1 EIP per subnet/zone and by default EKS uses a minimum of 2 zones.

This is a working example you may found useful:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: "subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,subnet-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations: "eipalloc-wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww,eipalloc-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
```

I hope this is useful to you

Comment: yup, good answer but too specific -- folks just grab the annotations and jump off the page before upvoting I guess